# How to get a value from Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I have a Observable of service data which return true or false value ,when call the servive which returns

```
 let m =this.myService.checkCapabilityOf(constantvalue);
console.log(m);
```

[image]

below format[image]
[image]

Here in the observable value it return false,
I need to get the value 
so i have subscribe the observable.

```
let m =this.myService.checkCapabilityOf(constantvalue).subscribe(value => value);
console.log(m);
```

But it returns below format , howto get a value from observable[image]

Comment: You put the access to the value **inside the callback**, where you have it.

Comment: @johnSharp why it is not showing in scope variable after subscribe

Comment: What do you mean *"in scope variable"*? I'd strongly recommend reading up on the basics of async.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get the value from Observable subscribe.

```
let m;
this.myService.checkCapabilityOf(constantvalue).subscribe(value =>{ 
 m = value
 console.log(value);
```

});

Remember that it is an async call then you can not get the value from out site of the subscribe. you can save the reference  or get a copy of the object but just until the subscribe responses you will get the value.